# How to pass string lines as cl_uint array and file details to the GPGPU?

Tags: c++, opencl

How to load lines of a text file, the lines' lengths and the amount of read lines, cast them the right way and pass them to the GPU?

Meaning:

**Input text file:**

```
Line1
Line2
..
LineN
```

**app.cl**

```
#define UP_LIMIT 256

typedef struct {
  uint bar; // amount of read lines
} foomatic;

typedef struct {
   uint len; // length of line
   uchar s[UP_LIMIT]; // line
} foo;

__kernel foobar(__global foo * kernel_in, __global foomatic kernel_in2){
 // do something
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define LLEN 256
typedef struct {
   cl_uint bar; // amount of read lines
} foomatic;
typedef struct {
   cl_uint len; // length of line
   cl_uchar s[LLEN]; // line
} foo;
int main(){
// load from file
// count lines of file
foo * input = new foo[N]; // N is the amount of lines of source text file
// cast line to cl_uchar

// pass lines, their lengths and number of lines to ocl kernel
delete [] input;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using struct in OpenCL seems to be tricky as the fields could be packed differently on the CPU and the device.  Also, it is not efficient on GPUs because it affects the ability to group memory accesses.  The better approach is to use multiple arrays.  I'd have something like this:

```
//N is the number of strings.
cl_uint* strlens = new cl_uint[N];
cl_uchar* input = new cl_uchar[N * LLEN];
cl_int err_code = CL_SUCCESS;
//Remember to check error codes, omitted here for convenience.
cl_mem strlens_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, N*sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, &err_code);
cl_mem input_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, N*LLEN*sizeof(cl_uchar), NULL, &err_code);

//Some initialisation code...

//Send to device.
err_code = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, strlens_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, N*sizeof(cl_uint), strlens, 0, NULL, NULL);
err_code = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, input_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, N*LLEN*sizeof(cl_uchar), 0 NULL, NULL);

//Send work to the GPU...

//Clean up.
delete[] strlens;
delete[] input;
```

I have used context and queue for the OpenCL context associated with your device and the command queue associated with that context.